# selectedindexchanged event of dropdownlist is not working with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

hello I have a `dropdownlist`. I am using jquery plugin to give style to `dropdownlist`. jquery plugin is **jquery.dd.js**. but my problem is `selectedindexchanged` event is not working in Internet exlorer 8 although it is working fine in other browsers.

Comment: we need to see some code and more information about context

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#yourSelectId').change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $('#yourSelectId option:selected').attr('value');
});
```

you will get the value inside selectedVal

Comment: This did not work for me. But the next answer worked

Answer (score 1):

Think would be better to use .val()

```
$('#yourSelectId').change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $('#yourSelectId').val();
});
```