# Website code in asp.net that is dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql

I have been assigned a project that seems challenging to do. [image] On this webpage, I want a new section to be added under module* when "computer request" is clicked. The section will be called "cost center" with a textbox on the side to input information. I want it to look like the Subject* line with the textbox but instead of subject i want a new line under module.

All of the data is used dynamically. Could anyone point me in the right direction to where to start? Apparently I need to use client side code..

Answer (score 1):

You might like to investigate the [UpdatePanel control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx).  This might help you do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

placeholder is a very good choice for your scenario. It is useful when any user wants to bind a dynamic control and we can fix its position too.
Very simple demo at : http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Asp-Control/DealwithaspplaceholdercontrolfromcodebehindC.htm

Answer (score 0):

why not create the item on the page and when the value "computer request" is selected, hide or show it? You can do this by setting the autopostback property on your dropdownlist to true and can test against it in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this completely in client-side code, just create the "Cost Center" row and set visibility to `false`. Then wire up the `onchange` event of the dropdown list to a javascript function that checks if the "Computer Request" item was selected. If it was, change the visibility to `true`. (You could also use jQuery [to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746752/selectedindexchanged-event-of-dropdownlist-is-not-working-with-jquery)).

**Edit**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourSelectId').change(function() {
        var selectedVal = $('#yourSelectId option:selected').attr('value');
        if(selectedVal == computerRequestItemValue)
            $('#costCenterRow').show();
        else
            $('#costCenterRow').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: could you give me example code of what that should look like?

Comment: Thanks, may you also explain what goes in the yourSelectId field, what option:selected does and what can go into the value vield?