# Javascript for onchange event in asp dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm looking for example code to use for javascript to check if the item  was selected in a dropdownlist. and then making it visible.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: **Things** becoming visible, are those `div`s or something?

Comment: making what visible ? please elaborate your question.

Comment: @yogi the item in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2):

i would do: (with jquery):

```js
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= AspControlName.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "TheValueYouWant") {
                $("#WhatToShowID").show();
            } else {
                $("#WhatToHideID").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This seems correct, but I have no clue how to use jquery. is there any other code i would need to use on the c# side and my page load?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this using C# in the code you could do:

Example HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" autopostback="true" runat="server">            </asp:DropDownList>
```

C# Code

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Make sure everything is hidden
    item_1_extra_stuff.Visible = false;
    item_2_extra_stuff.Visible = false;

    switch (DropDownList1.Text) {
        case "Item 1":
            item_1_extra_stuff.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "Item 2":
            item_2_extra_stuff.Visible = true;
            break;
    }

}
```

The postback allows the dropdown list to trigger that event, then the case statement just checks what the current input and runs show/hides required.

Comment: thanks, i'll try this. it seems more simple for me to understand. so if i use this then i wouldn't need any javascript code?

Comment: Exactly no JS needed with this approach, also if this works mark the answer as accepted please.

Comment: this is what im trying to do, someone mentioned to use autopostback also. i just need to figure out how to use code behind i think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564871/website-code-in-asp-net-that-is-dynamic/11565277#11565277

Comment: Basically, in Visual Studio if you double click on a dropdown it will generate the SelectIndexChange function for you to add the code into.